# Should i use remote or local service for this scenario?

Tags: android

I need to build some kind of listener,

now this listener suppose to run activies of diffrentz appz
, 
i want this listener to be as a service that will run the appropriate activity,

should i make it as a remote service or local service(for this i need some app to hold it - make sense?)  what will fit in?

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend running as a remote service as it sounds like you are planning on implementing this as a background service independent of any single activity.